# connect to router with Admin credentials in c#

Tags: router

I want to connect to wifi router with Admin credentials using C#. I have list of wifi available connections when I select one I want to connect to that router with the admin credential using C#. Please help me to achieve this or share your inputs.

Thanks in advance